# What can be written after table name dot in vba apart from column name?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have following query, when I run this it asks for parameter value for 'Mike Account'. I don't have this column called Mike Account in customer table.

```
SELECT [Customer].[Name]
, [Customer].[City]
, [Customer].[Mike Account] 
FROM
([Orders] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON [Orders].[Customer Key] = [Customer].[Customer Key]) 
INNER JOIN [Inventory Master] 
    ON [Orders].[Item Key] = [Inventory Master].[Item Key] 
WHERE ((([Orders].[Order Date])<Date()-7) 
    AND (([Customer].[Account Manager])=[forms]![Main Console]![User]) 
    AND (([Quantity on Hand]+[BO Quantity on Hand]+[Quantity on Order])=0));
```

What can be 'Mike Account' apart from column name ?

Comment: I retagged this as MS Access.  It is clearly not MySQL.

Comment: Check the 3rd line of your SQL statement, you use `[Customer].[Mike Account]`. If the field `[Mike Account]` does not exist, then Access will assume it is a named parameter, and prompt you for its value. You might want to check you haven't made a typo in the SQL?

Comment: You may use the Query builder to avoid this type of Typos (Assuming that there is a typo)

Comment: @Lucky there is no typo

Comment: If you don't have the column, [Mike Account] in your table, what is the need of keeping it in your select statement. Am I missing anything here!?

Comment: @Lucky it has been used in many places. I am trying to understand code.

Comment: If so, it could be a deleted column as @Andre mentioned

Comment: It could be an aliased name as in a query: `SELECT Customer.[Mike Account] FROM (SELECT  [Account Manager] AS [Mike Account] FROM Customer WHERE   [Account Manager] = 'Mike Account') Customer` but it's a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

At this position in the SELECT query, `[Mike Account]` can **only** be a column name.

So it's either a typo, or the column was deleted or renamed.

Comment: Its not a typo. It has been used in many places but unable to know why it is used

Comment: @jdcoderocks: Wild guess: Some time ago, a guy named Mike worked there. He or some manager needed to track his accounts. So someone added the column "Mike Account" as a quick&dirty hack. Some time later, Mike left. More time later (perhaps just recently) somebody noticed the column, remembered the story of its creation, and deleted the column.

Comment: No, in this scenario they wanted to track all customers that are assigned to Mike. It would have been a flag.

Comment: can there be any other scenario

Comment: Of course, as I said: "wild guess". But our guess will be even worse than yours. Can't you ask someone who worked with that database before? Or does it even matter? The column is gone, the queries will need to be fixed.